# How to protect a file from copying?

Tags: windows

I want to make some confidential files unmovable in windows 10 so that no one can either copy/move/delete the file.
Thanks in advance!!
Is there a Way??
I have tried using CMD code "cacls  /e /c /d %username%"
but it shows error like "no mapping between account names and security ids was done."

Comment: What's the use of a file that cannot be copied? To achieve this, this file should not be readable in any way

Comment: The file could be made accessible only to a service, for indirect use by client applications. It has to be in a directory that grants delete-child access only to the service account, administrators, and SYSTEM. This particular right on the parent directory matters because it allows deleting files in the directory even if their individual security doesn't allow or denies delete access. The file itself should only grant access to the service account, administrators, and SYSTEM. Use icacls.exe for these changes. cacls.exe is deprecated because it doesn't properly support inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

CACLS allows you to modify ACL rights on files and folders for users and groups on the local computer.

I needed this for an installed program would not run under a users account unless i manually change the user permissions of the folder.

The following can be added into a script to automate the procedure when installing the program!
4 Steps total
Step 1: Usage

```
cacls filename [/t] [/e] [/c] [/g user|group:perm]
```

Step 2: Parameters

filename Displays ACLs of specified directory, file or files.

/t Changes ACLs of specified files in the current directory and all
subdirectories.

/e Edit ACL instead of replacing it.

/c Continue changing ACLs, ignoring errors.

/g user|group:perm Grant specified user or group access permissions.
perm can be:

r Read
c Change (write)
f Full control

/r user Revoke specified user's or group's access permissions.

/p user|group:perm Replace specified user's or group's access
permissions. perm can be:

n None
r Read
c Change (write)
f Full control

/d user|group Deny specified user access.
Step 3: User|Group

can be a user or an AD Group!
Step 4: Example:

```
cacls c:\ /t /e /g Administrators:f
```

Gives "Administrators" group FULL access to C: Drive and all files / folders.